# Stardew Valley Traveling Cart inventory set at save time?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm wondering when the game determine the inventory the traveling merchant will sell? Is it locked in right after you save at the end of the day or is it randomized when you get up.  I've tried reloading it a couple of times and it seemed like it won't change that way. (No save scumming)

I ask because I've noticed some meals I get in the mail aren't the same if I reload the save file.  If they are set in stone it would let you run there after waking up and seeing if there's anything worth buying (saving you time if there's nothing good).

Comment: Didn't you answer that yourself in the question? If you've tried reloading and saw no changes, it's very unlikely that you just happened to get the same exact inventory again randomly.

Comment: Well the thing with the food in the mail is some inconsistency i would say.

Comment: When i looked at the save file, i noticed a lot of things are set in it. I specifically saw things about the next days weather. So i can not confirm such a thing, but i would bet it is set right before the game is saved for the next day.

Comment: Next days weather has to be set in the save file because of the weather report .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I took a look at the decompiled source code and found that the traveling cart inventory is determined by the value of *uniqueIDForThisGame* (which is randomly generated when you start a new game), combined with the number of days passed since the start of the game.

This means the cart's inventory for each day in the game was effectively set in stone way back when you first started the game.

The value of *uniqueIDForThisGame* is stored in the save file, so you should be able to change the cart's inventory by changing this number. But be warned: this value is used in dozens of places throughout the game, and changing it could have unpredictable effects. It might even make the game unplayable. If you really want to change it, do so at your own risk, and take backups first.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it five times now and the exact same options have appeared every time.  It does not seem possible to "save scum" to get a better outcome.

Answer (score -1):

If you open your Charactername_numberID file with an editor and search for uniqueIDForThisGame right next to it is shown your file number. Change that number, I had a 9 digit number and left the first and last digit as they were and changed the 7 others and the cart showed other items with each different number. But after you change that number, the game creates a new file with charactername_newnumberID when you save ingame after having done the changes. And from that moment on every saving will update that new file.

Comment: This was already mentioned

Comment: It would be better to upvote or comment on the other answers if you do not have anything new to add.